# How to bridge an existing "did change" data model with SwiftUI's ObservableObject?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine, publisher, observedobject

I have an existing model that looks like this:

```swift
struct Data { ... }

struct Parameters { ... }

final class Model {
    let dataDidChange: AnyPublisher<Void, Never> { ... }

    private(set) var data: Data
    var parameters: Parameters {
        didSet { ... }
    }
    
    ...
}
```

In this model, `dataDidChange` publisher fires at any time `data` or `parameters` **did** change. Also, `parameters` may be changed from other models, which will trigger the update.

I am trying to create SwiftUI view, that will mirror the model's state, allowing for representation of `data` on screen, and changing the `parameters`.

For this purpose I have created some kind of a view model for view to bind against:

```swift
final class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    private let model: Model

    var parameters: Parameters {
        get { self.model.parameters }
        set { self.model.parameters = newValue }
    }

    var data: Data { self.model.data }

    init(model: Model) {
        self.model = model

        model.dataDidChange
            .sink { self.objectWillChange.send() } // <-- This place
            .store(in: ...)
    }
}
```

And my view looks like this:

```swift
struct MyView: View {
    @ObservedObject var vm: ViewModel

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ParametersView(parameters: self.$vm.parameters)
            DataView(self.vm.data)
        }
    }
}
```

The thing that I don't like about this approach is that `objectWillChange` publisher is in fact triggered **after** the data has changed. Although it works, I am wondering, will it be any perfomance/correctness issues with this approach? `ObservableObject` documentation explicitly states, that

> A type of object with a publisher that emits **before** the object has changed.

**What is the preferred way to bridge "did change" style models to SwiftUI?**

Comment: How about using `@Observable` instead? You just need to attach the macro to the existing `Model`, and it will work with SwiftUI. You might need to mark some properties as `@ObservationIgnored`, but that's really it.

Comment: If you really want to have `class ViewModel: ObservableObject`, then all you need 
is `@Published var model: Model` and  make `Model` a struct, no need for the other stuff. 
Have a look at this Apple link  [Monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app) it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app. Note however, if you are targeting ios17+, 
use this approach [Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app) for managing data in your App.

Comment: @Sweeper unfortunately, I am targeting macOS 13, so it is not possible to use `Observation` for me.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I can't make `Model` a struct, because it is shared library code, so i need to specifically bridge it as-is. I may use `@Published var data: Data` and update it manually, but it will lead to memory duplication in `Model` and in `ViewModel` for large `Data`.

Comment: Ok, then try using `@Published var model: Model` in your `ViewModel` with your existing `Model` class, see if that works.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine It is not working, as expected tho. Changes in members of a `class` do not trigger a `willSet` block, so it is not viable option. It is working only if the instance of `model` gets substituted for another instance, because it will trigger the `willSet` block in `@Published`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to create a view model, then it should do something more interesting than simply rebroadcast information that the view could get from the model itself.  Otherwise your view could just be observing the model directly.  In this case the view could use the `onReceive` view modifier watch the model's publisher directly.

SwiftUI uses the `objectWillChange` notification to note down that *in the next event cycle* the view will have to be redrawn. It really doesn't matter if that notification comes before the model changes or after it changes because the effect (redrawing the view) is delayed until the next event cycle. All that really matters is that the data is in place by the time the next event cycle starts and the view is redrawn.

Comment: Thanks! I provided "simple" view model case, but in reality I have more complicated view models. I was wondering if SwiftUI performs any diffing between state in the moment when `objectWillChange` is received and the state after one event cycle, thus, rebroadcasting `didSet` to `objectWillChange` may somehow mess the diffing logic. So far, it works.